# Rails and Rspec - Has One Through Polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, polymorphic-associations, shoulda

I am trying to test a has_one :through relationship in rails using shoulda matchers.

My relationship structure looks like this (it's a reverse polymorphic association - https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485 )

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
  has_many :videos, through: :contents, source: :item, source_type: "Video"
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :content, as: :item
  has_one :container, through: :contents
end
```

This is my shoulda matcher code in Rspec:

```
# video_spec.rb
it { should have_one(:container).through(:contents) }
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm receiving this error and how to properly test this association?

Comment: Is that *all* of the code in your spec file (shoulda matcher)? Where/How are you initializing the subject under test? Post that code, it could be a problem with how you are initializing your test data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's *all* the code in your spec file (I apologize if you simply posted a trimmed down version), then you need to nest the shoulda matcher under a `describe` block for the `Video` class:

```
describe Video do
  it { should have_one(:container).through(:contents) }
end
```

The error you're getting indicates that the subject under test is `nil`. By nesting the spec inside a `describe` block for the `Video` class, the subject under test is implicitly the `Video` class.

Take a peak at the [documentation in the source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb#L344), it has a ton of good examples in it.